# Android Date: Determining Future Date From Today

Tags: java, android

I have an app that allows users to set reoccurring alarms. In a fragment, they're allowed to pick a time from a TimePicker and set switches for what day they want the alarm to occur i.e. Mon,Wed,Fri.

I'm saving the time from the TimePicker in milliseconds and the days they choose as a string in an Alarm object like below.

```
public class Alarm  extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private Long time;
private String title;
private String dayOfWeek;}
```

What I'm trying to determine is how I figure out the future dates based on the days they want to schedule. For example, if today is Monday and they want to schedule an alarm for Mon, Wed and Fri, I would save an alarm object with a time of today, another alarm object with a time of today + 2 days and lastly one with an alarm of + 4 days.

However, the issue is this changes based on what day today is. If today is Tuesday, then I'll need to schedule an alarm for + 1 day, +3 days and + 6 days. What's the easiest way to calculate this day offset?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would consider adding user shared preference (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

containing a string alarmDaysOfWeek="Mon,Wed,Fri" or whatever value is based on user input.

Then you'd implement a Service that checks current day of week against the alarmDaysOfWeek in user's SharedPreferences and alarms if it's a match.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion:-

Set an alarm for everyday and when an Alarm Occur(Service,BroadcastReceiver) then check it if you have to something today(as par user's selection) or just do nothing.

By above ways you wont need calculations for +1 or +2.

Comment: How would I take account for repeating alarms? Each alarm would repeat weekly so if I set them to fire every day, then I'd essentially also have to reschedule them for each day as well?

Answer (score 0):

I was able resolve this by capturing what day the user selected and then setting the day of the week on the calendar object like newAlarm.setDayOfWeek(x.getDayOfWeek) and then setting the time of the alarm object based on that. This way of a user selected a time in the past i.e. if today were Tuesday and they set an alarm for Monday, it would actually set the calendar object time in the past. Then when the alarm was scheduled, it would immediately fire and I could reschedule it for +7 days or next Monday.